# How can i remove the first comma in a string in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this string 'SELECT * FROM Board WHERE ArtikelNr IN (,5,2,1,3) ORDER BY name ASC' How can I remove the first ',' from ',5,2,1,3'?

This is the code I am using the following code

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Board WHERE ArtikelNr IN (";

                   foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
                       $sql.=$id.",";
                   }

                   $sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY name ASC";
```

Comment: https://www.regex101.com/r/dQ1gU8/1

Comment: You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 4):

in PHP, try

```
ltrim($str,',') ;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php

if comma is into the $str,

```
 preg_replace('/,/', '',  $str, 1);
```

in MySQL, try,

```
SELECT SUBSTR('your_string', 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

`ltrim($str, ',')` will work for only preceding `,`.

If it can be anywhere then `str_replace()` is little better method than `preg_replace`.

`$str = str_replace(',','',$str,1)` 1 to replace only the first , and then not proceed any more. http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

if you need to know exact position of the 'comma' character, user `strpos()` method.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP please try below code:

```
$string = ",'A','B','c'";
$updatedStr = trim($string,",");
echo $updatedStr;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace in PHP to remove the first comma in a string

```
preg_replace('/(.*?),/', '\1', $string);
```

See the PHP docs for more information:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Shouldn't the regex be delimited?

Comment: This is removing all commas in string. If you only want to remove the first comma:
preg_replace('/^,/', '', $string);

Answer (score 0):

4th parameter of `preg_replace()` is limit:

```
$zm = 'al,aola,ola,ola';
$zm = preg_replace('/,/', '', $zm, 1);
echo $zm;
```